kvm/libvirt Windows 11 guest cannot shutdown after logout
I have Windows 11 KVM(libvirt) guest. It can be shutdown by virsh shutdown if it is login, otherwise cannot.
"Allow system to be shut down without having to log on" is enabled. That is actually the default.

Anyone has clue?
Update:
If I start the VM, without login, virsh shutdown works.
However, if I RDP into the box, sign out, then virsh shutdown does not work anymore.

the fact that you sign out suggests it has nothing to do with being logged in, since you sign out you are not logged in

@JaromandaX The problem is when I am NOT logged in.

That's because after logging out via RDP, the session is remaining active or holding resources that prevent virsh shutdown from working properly.
This is common in virtual environments with remote sessions.
Fix: Configure Windows to end disconnected RDP sessions immediately.

Go to Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
Navigate to: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Session Time Limits.
Enable Set time limit for disconnected sessions and set it to 0 minutes.

This forces the session to end, allowing virsh shutdown to work as expected.
ELSE
If the previous fails, you can try by disabling "Sign-in info is used to automatically finish setting up after an update" in Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options.
This setting can prevent the shutdown command from working as expected post-logout.


The minimum for that option is 1min. I am testing that now.
If I click "Sign out", do I still need this? Or is there another way if I don't want to affect non-sign-out but disconnect session.


I enabled that option with 1min. However "virsh shutdown ..." still does not work even I waited 5min.

I edited my answer, I truly hope it solves the issue.

Tested the new option, still doesn't work.

Control Panel -> System and Security -> Power Options --> Click "Change plan Settings".  Set  "Turn off the display" to Never
If that doesn't work, I am sorry I could help you, I've had that issue and did fix it in 2023.

I tested and still the same.
